# Why isn't my GUI showing up?

Tags: java, user-interface, calculator

I have been working on a GUI calculator, but it is not working properly. When i run the program, the frame does not show up. This is my program:

```
package mycalc;

/**
 *
 * @author haysa
 */

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class MyCalc {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

    JFrame f;
    JTextField first, second;
    JButton bdiv,bmul,bsub,badd,beq;


    bdiv=new JButton("/");
    bmul=new JButton("*");
    bsub=new JButton("-");
    badd=new JButton("+");
    beq=new JButton("=");


    bsub.setBounds(250,240,50,40);
    bmul.setBounds(250,170,50,40);
    bdiv.setBounds(250,100,50,40);
    badd.setBounds(250,310,50,40);
    beq.setBounds(180,310,50,40);



    first=new JTextField("");
    second=new JTextField("");

    f=new JFrame("Calculator");

    f.add(bdiv);
    f.add(bmul);
    f.add(bsub);
    f.add(badd);

    }  
}
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with my program. It keeps saying that build is successful but nothing appears. I know I need to add something, but I'm not sure what to add, or where to put it. Please help me :D

Comment: You need to make the frame visible. ie f.setVisible(true); I am not sure how you are trying to run your program though.

Comment: Before posting such a question, you should consider googling instead.

Answer (score 4):

After you declare your frame, `f`, you have to use `setVisible(true);`, or else the window will not appear. You may notice the java icon in your desktop, because it did open the window, however it can not be clicked, moved, or (obviously) seen.

```
//...
f=new JFrame("Calculator");
f.setVisible(true); //added this line
f.add(bdiv);
f.add(bmul);
f.add(bsub);
f.add(badd);
//...
```

As of now, your window will be very small(set the size using `f.setSize(x, y)`), and it will appear in the top left corner of your screen. To make the top left of your window appear in the middle of your screen, use `f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);`. And one more thing is you have to set the layout to null (`f.setLayout(null)`) otherwise your `setBounds()` method won't work. Please comment below if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the f.setVisible(true) function and if you use setBounds(x,y,w,h) then you need to set the layout of JFrame to null like this f.setLayout(null);

```
class MyCalc{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

JFrame f=new JFrame("Calculator");
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setSize(555,555);
f.setLayout(null);
JTextField first, second;
JButton bdiv,bmul,bsub,badd,beq;


bdiv=new JButton("/");
bmul=new JButton("*");
bsub=new JButton("-");
badd=new JButton("+");
beq=new JButton("=");


bsub.setBounds(250,240,50,40);
bmul.setBounds(250,170,50,40);
bdiv.setBounds(250,100,50,40);
badd.setBounds(250,310,50,40);
beq.setBounds(180,310,50,40);



first=new JTextField("");
second=new JTextField("");



f.add(bdiv);
f.add(bmul);
f.add(bsub);
f.add(badd);
f.setVisible(true);
}  

}
```